# Kernel Density estimation with guassian kernel function why don't have indicator function like other kernels

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Kernel Density estimation with guassian kernel function why  don't have indicator function like other kernels.

Comment: Kernel density estimation is defined the same way *no matter what kernel do you use*, this makes your question unclear. Could you please edit to make it more prececise?

Comment: It's better if you edit your question to its previous state, also explaining a bit since you've accepted my answer.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since after you edited your question it was even more unclear, also since you accepted the answer to the previous version of the question, the edit does not have seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear; it seems like you're asking for the appearance of *indicator* functions present in specific [kernel](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kernel_(statistics)#/Kernel_functions_in_common_use) functions. Some kernels are non-zero in specific intervals, e.g. uniform, triangular kernels; but Gaussian kernel is non-zero everywhere in the real line. So, its functional form doesn't require any indicators. The uniform kernel, on the contrary, can be written as $K(x)=1/2$, if $|x|\leq 1$ and $0$ if $|x|>1$, or more compactly using indicators: $K(x)=\mathcal{I}(|x|\leq 1)/2$.

**Edit:** Your question was unclear, and with the edit you've made, it's more unclear.